# Is there a way to compile C++ several files using Clang in one process?

Tags: c++, compilation, benchmarking, clang

For benchmarking reason, I need to use the Clang (clang++) compiler to compile several C++ files using only one process.

Indeed, by default, the compiler use several process to compile the files and that makes my benchmark to not works the way I want.

I know this is a uncommon question, but this is only for a special case, in general, I don't need that.

Edit : It is breaking my benchmark, because I generate a call graph of the execution using CallGrind and then I've several call graphs, one by process

Edit 2 : From what I understand, clang++ is forking to clang for every file

Comment: Concatenation won't produce the same result.

Comment: OP: This is a silly requirement. Fix your benchmark.

Comment: In general yes.. but it could work for his case

Comment: if you use `clang++ file1.cc file2.cc -o app`, does it use 2 processes?

Comment: How is this breaking your benchmark, exactly?

Comment: I know this is a silly requirement, but I don't know how to fix the benchmark, because it comes from CallGrind not really me. 
It's breaking my benchmark because Callgrind is generating me several call graph file and I cannot bench the whole thing. 
Apparently, clang++ is forking to clang.

Comment: @Evan: It will spawn `clang -cc1 -further-args ...` twice. Also, clang will spawn two copies of `as` and one instance of `gcc` on my system. You can verify this by passing the `-###` flag to clang.

Comment: Right, On my computer it forks two clang once per file and then once to ld. For now I resolved the problem using an Unity Build, but if there is another solution, I'm still interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the result of `clang++ file1.cc -c -###` (plus whatever flags you need).  You should be able to stuff additional input files into the command starting with `clang -cc1`, and have them all compile without any forking.  This mode of operation isn't really supported, but it works as far as I know.